# Ошибка при использовании Eclipse + Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Только начинаю осваивать Java. При использовании сервера Tomcat + Eclipse возникла проблема.
Сам сервер установился нормально, по адресу localhost:8080 отображается страница приветствия. В Eclipse его добавила, но при попытке стартовать его из Eclipse выводится ошибка. В чем может быть причина?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Написано же, что искомый файл отсутствует.